# Appending one QByteArray to another QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I wrote the following function, which is supposed to allow me to append some input QByteArray data to a private QByteArray inside of my class:

```
void addQByteArray(QByteArray* array)
{
    p_commandArray.append(array);
}
```

My understanding is that the append function should also accept a QByteArray as a parameter, but I'm getting this error when I try to compile:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘QByteArray*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
>            p_commandArray.append(array);
>                                       ^

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes [`QByteArray::append`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) has an overload that you can pass a `QByteArray` (more precicelsy a `const QByteArray&`), but what you attempt to pass is a pointer to `QByteArray`.

Either

```
void addQByteArray(QByteArray& array)
{
    p_commandArray.append(array);
}
```

or

```
void addQByteArray(QByteArray* array)
{
    p_commandArray.append(*array);
}
```

Prefer the first (passing a reference), because using pointers only makes sense when a `nullptr` is a valid parameter, but when you pass a `nullptr` you shall not dereference it.

The error message you get is due to another overload of `append` that takes a `char` as parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It woks like a charm now :-).

Comment: For the null case there's the default constructed bytearray (and .isNull()), so there is almost no case where one would pass a bytearray by pointer.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld the only reason I included it is because thats what OP had originally

Answer (score 2):

`QByteArray::append` accepts `const QByteArray&`, but you give it a pointer. Give it an object:

```
void addQByteArray(QByteArray* array) {
    p_commandArray.append(*array);
    //                    ^ dereference
}
```